# Equation of ellipsoid given foci and two semi-axes

Tags: conic-sections, 3d

How does one find the equation of an ellipsoid given two foci, $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$, and one semi-axis $l$? $c$ may not be equal to $f$.

Comment: In the title you say "two semi-axes", in the body it's "one semi-axis". Which way should it be?